# WSO2 Message Broker Error while adding Queue - Invalid Object Name

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-message-broker

I have just set up a **WSO2 Message Broker 3.0.0** connecting to a SQL Server DB.

The DB for the Carbon MB component has been created successfully as well.

The DB for the Message Broker Data store is created and contains the table *MB_QUEUE_MAPPING*.

However when adding a Queue via the MB UI I see the following error in the stack trace:

```
[2015-12-16 15:00:41,472] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl} -  Error occurred while retrieving destination queue id for destina
tion queue TestQ
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'MB_QUEUE_MAPPING'.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029)
        at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl.getQueueID(RDBMSMessageStoreImpl.java:1324)
        at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl.getCachedQueueID(RDBMSMessageStoreImpl.java:1298)
        at org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl.addQueue(RDBMSMessageStoreImpl.java:1634)
        at org.wso2.andes.store.FailureObservingMessageStore.addQueue(FailureObservingMessageStore.java:445)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.AMQPConstructStore.addQueue(AMQPConstructStore.java:116)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesContextInformationManager.createQueue(AndesContextInformationManager.java:154)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundQueueEvent.updateState(InboundQueueEvent.java:151)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundEventContainer.updateState(InboundEventContainer.java:167)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:67)
        at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:41)
        at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

The "Add Queue" screen does not go away however the Queue does get added to the *MB_QUEUE* table just fine in the DB. Both tables *MB_QUEUE_MAPPING* & *MB_QUEUE_COUNTER* are blank.

The "List Queues" screen does blank despite a number of Queues in the MB_QUEUE table. Stack trace also shows errors but is not included as its not relevant to the error above.

I can create a Topic just fine however.

I want to know why MB would say the table MB_QUEUE_MAPPING is an **Invalid object name** when the table clearly exists ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the way you have configure the mysql database is incorrect.So you can better try out one of these below two scenarios to make sure about this issue.

1) starting the server for the first time with the -Dsetup parameter or

2) you can refer the documentation(https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Configuring+MySQL) "Configuring MySQL" and follow step by step instructions given in order.

I have tried out the second scenario and I did not get any exception when I am adding queue.And the document I have mentioned will have to be update as below.

you can see this command in the step 3.

```
 mysql -u <db_user_name> -p -D<database_name> < '<WSO2MB_HOME>/dbscripts/mb-store/mysql-mb.sql ';
```

db_user_name  - username of db.

database_name - database name that you have created in the step 1.

WSO2MB_HOME  - home directory path for MB.

Hope this could help you to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems user connecting to MSSQL database not having correct permission. Most probably `SELECT` permission. Reason why I am saying is, when you adding queue, it does get added. This means user has `INSERT` permission. Once queue added, page redirected to Queue List page. User must have `SELECT` permission to retrieve queue list. Topic are not getting added to database, it keeps in registry. You can verify user who connecting to MSSQL from configuration like below in `wso2mb-3.0.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml`.

```
<datasource>
   <name>WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>
   <jndiConfig>
       <name>WSO2MBStoreDB</name>
   </jndiConfig>
   <definition type="RDBMS">
         <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/wso2_mb</url>
                    <username>sa</username>
                    <password>sa</password>
                    <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>200</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
         </configuration>
     </definition>
</datasource>
```